# Audio event not firing when bind dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, audio, dom-events

I have an audio element `<audio>` (I am appending it to body via js) which is playing audio. If I bind event `onplay` in the html then it works.

```
<audio onplay="alert('t')" .... its working...
```

but if I am binding it via js then its not working.

```
document.getElementById('audio1').onplay = function() { alert('t'); }; //..... not working
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a proper way to attach event listeners, try:

```
document.getElementById('audio1').addEventListener('play',function() { alert('t'); });
```